# DVD Playback prohibited by area limitations

Tags: dvd, multimedia, burning

Need to shrink 8.5GB DVD to 4.7GB and burn a DVD with NTSC format. Sounds simple right?

I have tried several ways and combined different apps without success.
I have used different media DVD/RW+ DVD/R- and different brands.

The DVD player keeps saying "Playback prohibited by area limitations". I know the DVD burner/player **region code** is correct.

Here is my arsenal of applications I have used:

AcidRip DVD ripper, Arista Transcoder, which doesn't work right because of a bug!, Avidmux (GTK), Bombono DVD, Brasero, DeVeDe, Dvd95, DVD::Rip, HandBrake, K3B, Nero Linux and WinFF

Comment: Is the DVD [PAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL_region) or NTSC?. A google search of that error brought me to [this forum post](http://forum.slysoft.com/showthread.php?t=37807) indicating that this was the problem. It might not be a region code issue, it might be a PAL vs NTSC issue. Don't have an answer but I hope that's a clue.

Comment: @Tom Brossman NTSC is the format. Will look at the forum post.

Comment: When you say "The DVD player keeps saying ..." are you referring to a standalone DVD player connected to a tv? No burned DVD_VIDEO disk is encumbered by region coding, they are in essence region-free or all region. So the issue with your standalone *if this is the case), is you've encoded to wrong format or some standalone players can have issue with DVD_VIDEO discs that aren't region coded (protected

Comment: @Doug Yes the stand alone player attached to the TV

Comment: Have you absolutely confirmed that the burned disk is or is marked in the VIDEO_TS.IFO as NTSC? If not you can do so fairly easily thru mediainfo. Open mediainfo-gui, go File > open files & browse to Filesystem >  /media/your_dvd/VIDEO_TS/. First open VTS_01_1.VOB & ck. Then open VIDEO_TS.IFO & also check for NTSC. You need to ck. both. If you need some help with this I'll post complete as an answer

Comment: Yes, It is NTSC. Verified on the original and the copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used DVD shrink and K3B to do the job